# asp.net make custom control in website

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls

I want to make a custom control in my website.

Following is the Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace AnkitControls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for CustomTreeView
    /// </summary>
    public class CustomTreeViewControl : WebControl
    {

    }
}
```

Default.aspx :

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
    <%@ Register Assembly="AnkitControls" Namespace="AnkitControls" TagPrefix="CustomCtrl" %>
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        Welcome to ASP.NET!
    </h2>
    <p>
        To learn more about ASP.NET visit <a href="http://www.asp.net" title="ASP.NET Website">www.asp.net</a>.
    </p>
    <p>
        You can also find <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=152368&amp;clcid=0x409"
            title="MSDN ASP.NET Docs">documentation on ASP.NET at MSDN</a>.
    </p>
</asp:Content>
```

When i compile the site, it gives me error for assembly.

Comment: Which error ? Please give all relevant information when asking, including full exception message and stack trace. And, by the way, you did not ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it in the the App_Code than write `Assembly=__code`

if it is ddl then write DLL name `Assembly=dllname`

Comment: thanks. I placed my code in App_Code and was not able to use the assembly.